# weird display, program doesn't run all the time

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a program running sometime alright, the other time it just won't. The odds is roughly 50-50. Those are the snapshots when I run the program. Without looking at my code, does anybody know any scenarios this might happens?  I am just confused, by the way, the program can't be stop normally either when it displays the white screen, I had to kill the process to terminate it, I am guess there is a thing with the JVM, correct me if I am wrong. Thanks [image: Properly displayed]

I know this is not the way I should post the question, but the code is gigantic and I am not even sure where it might go wrong. My confusion is why it works 50% of the time, not all or nothing situation. Thanks

[image: stuck somewhere]

Comment: Without looking at my car, can you tell me why it's not working? Doctor, without a description of where I might or might not feel well, can you tell me what's wrong? Be serious - there is absolutely zero information here that can be used to help you without the use of ESP. Voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: I know this is not the way I should post the question, but the code is gigantic and I am not even sure where it might go wrong. My confusion is why it works 50% of the time, not all or nothing situation. Thanks

Comment: Without looking at your code I can see that your doing the UI on different threads.

Comment: @ClintHui: Try reproducing the problem with a much simpler program. Cut out all unnecessary liens of code that aren't related to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Java Swing, this kind of thing is often a symptom of doing GUI work (calls on methods on Swing or AWT objects) on any thread other than Swing's GUI thread. Make sure you're dispatching correctly to prevent that.

EDIT: Adding these links to some docs on the subject to get you started:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html
http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, it might be the case. That's all I am looking for. Thank you very much